# Remove leading zero from d3.js timeFormat

Tags: javascript, d3.js, time

I'm working with d3.js and I'm using [this documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format).

I use this to show the hour: `%I:%M` which shows the hour like `02:34`.

Is there a way to remove the leading zero, in this case showing the data as `2:34` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As outlined [in the documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#locale_format), the default padding is zero-padding for all directives except `%e` (for which it is space-padding).
To change the padding type, you can [append a modifier](https://www.karltarvas.com/2017/09/22/d3js-remove-leading-zero-from-time-format.html) to `%`:

- `0` - zero-padding
- `_` - space-padding
- `-` - disable padding

So, given your example: `%-I:%M`.

Answer (score 2):

`%-I` will get rid of the leading zero.